# Rolling array around

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have

```
arr = np.arange(6)
arr
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

and I decide that I want to treat an array "like a circle": When I run out of material at the end, I want to start at index 0 again. That is, I want a convenient way of selecting `x` elements, starting at index `i`.

Now, if `x == 6`, I can simply do

```
i = 3
np.hstack((arr[i:], arr[:i]))
Out[9]: array([3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2])
```

But is there a convenient way of generally doing this, even if `x > 6`, without having to manually breaking the array apart and thinking through the logic?

For example:

```
print(roll_array_arround(arr)[2:17])
```

should return.

```
array([2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0])
```

Comment: You could write a function `roll_array_around(arr, startIndex, endIndex)` that returns an array. If you had a function `roll_array_around(arr)` - i.e., it just took `arr` as a parameter - then you would theoretically need to return an infinite array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See mode='wrap' in ndarray.take:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html

Taking your hypothetical function:

```
print(roll_array_arround(arr)[2:17])
```

If it is implied that it is a true slice of the original array that you are after, that is not going to happen; a wrapped-around array cannot be expressed as a strided view of the original; so if you seek a function that maps an ndarray to an ndarray, this will necessarily involve a copy of your data.

That is, efficiency-wise, you shouldnt expect to find solution that significantly differs in performance from the expression below.

```
print(arr.take(np.arange(2,17), mode='wrap'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Modulus operation seems like the best fit here -

```
def rolling_array(n, x, i):
    # n is rolling period
    # x is length of array
    # i is starting number
    return np.mod(np.arange(i,i+x),n)
```

Sample runs -

```
In [61]: rolling_array(n=6, x=6, i=3)
Out[61]: array([3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2])

In [62]: rolling_array(n=6, x=17, i=2)
Out[62]: array([2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution you can look into would probably be :

```
from itertools import cycle
list_to_rotate = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
rotatable_list = cycle(list_to_rotate)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to `roll` your array.

```
>>> x = np.arange(10)
>>> np.roll(x, 2)
array([8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

See [numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) for more details.

Comment: I don't think that is what OP means. OP is trying to use an array as an infinite circular queue. Look at OP's example, `len(arr)` is just `6`, but OP wants to get  `arr[2:17]` which definitely exceeds even double length.